# NxLog delete file after processing

Tags: log-files, nxlog

I would like to delete the logfile once processing, what I did:

```
<Extension multiline>
    Module      xm_multiline
    Exec        if $raw_event =~ /^\s*$/ drop();
    HeaderLine  /Debut du job/
</Extension>

<Input in1>
    Module      im_file
    File        '/opt/appl/appli/logs/*.nxlog'
    InputType   multiline
    Exec        $nxlog_message = $raw_event;
    Exec        $nxlog_tags = "appli";
    Exec        $nxlog_hostname = hostname();
    Exec        $nxlog_filename = file_name();
    Exec        to_json();
</Input>

<Extension exec_out>
    Module      xm_exec
</Extension>


<Output fileout1>
     Module      om_file
     File        "/tmp/test.log"
     Exec        exec_async("/bin/rm" + $nxlog_filename);
</Output>
```

For now, nothing happened… I'm looking forward for idea.

Thx for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that *exec_async()* should not receive the arguments concatenated to the command, i.e. you need this instead:

```
Exec        exec_async("/bin/rm", $nxlog_filename);
```

I'd recommend using the built in [file_remove()](https://nxlog.co/docs/nxlog-ce/nxlog-reference-manual.html#xm_fileop_proc_file_remove) instead of invoking */bin/rm*.

Comment: Thx, file_remove() do the trick :)